# excel vba method addpicture sometimes it won't work

Tags: excel, vba, image

```
    Option Explicit
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim Filename As String

Sub URLPictureInsert()
    Dim theShape As Shape
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCol As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Set to the range of cells you want to change to pictures
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D3")
    For Each cell In rng
        Filename = cell
        ' Use Shapes instead so that we can force it to save with the document
        Set theShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture( _
            Filename:=Filename, linktofile:=msoFalse, _
            savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
            Left:=cell.Left, Top:=cell.Top, Width:=60, Height:=60)
        If theShape Is Nothing Then GoTo isnill
        With theShape
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            ' Shape position and sizes stuck to cell shape
            .Top = cell.Top + 1
            .Left = cell.Left + 1
            .Height = cell.Height - 2
            .Width = cell.Width - 2
            ' Move with the cell (and size, though that is likely buggy)
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With
        ' Get rid of the
        cell.ClearContents
isnill:
        Set theShape = Nothing
        Range("D2").Select

    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Debug.Print "Done " & Now


End Sub
```

---

Mostly, the stated code can help me to transfer the urls to images. But some urls won't work.
such as this link:
https://www.revolvecn888.com/images/p4/n/d/AGOL-WJ95_V1.jpg
it can not be transfered to images.

Comment: Could you elaborate what *"sometimes not work"* mean? Remove `On Error Resume Next` and see if you get any runtime error. If yes, check what it says - likely it's just an invalid filename

Comment: The error is Error: (1004). Still I am confused.

Comment: The file you give as example loads for me - although it issues a warning when accessing it via https. A 1004 might happen if a file cannot be found or cannot be loaded: What is the error text you get?

Comment: a file cannot be found.  You are saying that on ur computer, you can load the url to image, am I right?
In that way, how it happened？ I can open the url on browser. Via vba code, it can not.

Comment: I used the same VBA command as you in your code - just with a hard coded URL and with http, not https. Do you have a typo in the URL? Cut and Paste the URL from the cell directly into the browser to check.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For this url. It solved.  Howerer, there are some other AWS urls still can not be transfered. I assume that is  the security reason.  I am considering to use python to fix it solidly. Thanks again.